# Sending File via peer mesh

Tags: wcf, p2p

can anybody help me or show some sample code in sending File on a peer mesh?

I google it already but cannot find any sample how to do it.

Thanks.

FBM

Comment: I guess you should state which technologies, frameworks etc' you are using.  Don't assume everyone is working on the same platform...

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but for reference - you may attract more answers if you show what you have written/found already. If this is a WCF component, are there really no online examples at microsoft.com?

Answer (score 0):

This is some code about file sharing via a mesh, maybe it's helpful to you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614028/Peer-to-Peer-File-Sharing-Through-WCF